# Linux: nm command 'G/g', 'p' and 'S/s' symbols types

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, nm

I'm trying to understand the outputs of `nm` command, but I'm not able to find `g`, `G`, `p`, `S` and `s` types on my object files or executables.

I tried to code many C programs, compiling those files with differents `gcc` flags but I didn't succeed :/

Any tips ?

Thanks in advance ;)

What I've tried so far:

- `nm` on several ELF64 and ELF32 not stripped executables `/bin/*`, `/usr/bin/*`, ...
- `nm` On my own `.o` (ELF) files and executables (ELF)
- `nm` On several dynamic libraries (`.so` / ELF): `/usr/share`, `/usr/lib`, ...

Comment: They might be legacy types that are unused in modern compilers. The `nm` man page on MacOS doesn't even mention `G/g` or `p`.

Comment: Yes That's not POSIX, but modern version of `nm` on some Linux distros are referencing these types on their man pages. Already tested on `Ubuntu 22.04` & `Debian 9`